# Nativescript ListView load's more on page loading

Tags: javascript, listview, nativescript

I use a `<ListView>` within my project, in view's XML file.

ListView has an attribute which invokes a function whenever you scroll down enough to see **last item** of ListView. 


**For more explanation**: the listview contains a template item which shows two elements, one is `<Label>` and other one is an `<Image>`


**The problem**: is that when I open the application, it loads multiple times.
¿What is the reason and how could it be prevented?

**home.xml**

```
<drawer:rad-side-drawer id="drawer">
<drawer:rad-side-drawer.mainContent>

  <!-- Home page contents -->
  <stack-layout loaded="contentLoaded">

    <ListView items="{{ photoList }}" id="photoList" row="1" colSpan="2" loadMoreItems="loadMorePhotos">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <GridLayout columns="*, auto" rows="auto,*">
                <Label row="0" imageid="{{id}}" text="{{title}}"/>
                <Image row="1" stretch="fill"  src="{{picture}}"/>
           </GridLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>

  </stack-layout>

</drawer:rad-side-drawer.mainContent>
<drawer:rad-side-drawer.drawerContent>
  <widgets:drawer-content />
</drawer:rad-side-drawer.drawerContent>
```

**drawer-content.xml**

```
<grid-layout class="drawer-content">
    <stack-layout>
        <!-- <label text="Home" tap="navigate" class="{{ selectedPage == 'home' ? 'selected' : '' }}" /> -->
        <ListView items="{{ menuList }}" id="menuList" row="1" colSpan="2">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <GridLayout columns="*, auto">
                    <Label text="{{ title }}" galleryid="{{id}}" tap="loadPhotos"/>
                </GridLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </stack-layout>
</grid-layout>
```

**home.js**

```
var MenuViewModel = require("../../shared/view-models/menu-view-model");
var PhotoViewModel = require("../../shared/view-models/photo-view-model");
var LoadingIndicator = require("nativescript-loading-indicator").LoadingIndicator;
var BasePage = require("../../shared/BasePage");
var observableModule = require("data/observable")
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var topmost = require("ui/frame").topmost;

var loader = new LoadingIndicator();
var loading_options = {
    message: 'دریافت اطلاعات ...',
    progress: 1,
    android: {
        indeterminate: false,
        cancelable: false,
        progressStyle: 0,
        secondaryProgress: 1
    },
    ios: {
        details: "",
        square: false,
        margin: 10,
        dimBackground: true,
        color: "#4B9ED6",
        mode: 0 // indeterminate
  }
};

var menuList = new MenuViewModel([]);
var photoList = new PhotoViewModel([]);
var current_gallery_id = 1;
var current_page = 1;
var isLoading = false;

var pageData = new observableModule.fromObject({
    menuList: menuList,
    photoList: photoList,
    page_title: 'آلبوم عکس',
    current_gallery_id: current_gallery_id,
    current_page: current_page,
});


var HomePage = function () {

};

HomePage.prototype = new BasePage();
HomePage.prototype.constructor = HomePage;

// Place any code you want to run when the home page loads here.
HomePage.prototype.contentLoaded = function (args) {

}

HomePage.prototype.pageLoaded = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    loader.show(loading_options);
    menuList.empty();
    menuList.load().then(function () {
        loader.hide();
    });
};

HomePage.prototype.loadPhotos = function (args) {
    var gallery_id = args.object.galleryid.toString();


    photoList.empty();
    page.getViewById("drawer").toggleDrawerState();

    if (current_gallery_id != gallery_id) {
        current_gallery_id = gallery_id;
        current_page = 1;

        console.log("Gallery Changed to : " + current_gallery_id);
    }

    loader.show(loading_options);
    photoList.load(gallery_id, current_page).then(function () {
        current_page++;
        console.log("Page Changed To : " + current_page);
        loader.hide();
        return;
    });


}

HomePage.prototype.loadMorePhotos = function (args) {

    var gallery_id = current_gallery_id;
    loader.show(loading_options);
    photoList.load(gallery_id, current_page).then(function () {
        current_page++;
        console.log("Page Changed To : " + current_page);
        console.log("Gallery is  : " + gallery_id);
        loader.hide();
    });
}


module.exports = new HomePage();
```

**Debug Console**

[image: output of console.log() when i click an item in drawer to get listview]

Comment: it loads multiple times means you're seeing the same items onScroll?

Comment: no . it invokes the function which attached to loadMoreItems.

Comment: @faouzi-oudouh , thankyou .

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a `timeout`to prevent `loadMorePhotos` from being called too many times..

```
   var timeout = setTimeout(loadMorePhotos, 100);

   clearTimeout(timeout);
```

*In your case :*

```
function getMorePhotos(){
  var gallery_id = current_gallery_id;
  loader.show(loading_options);
  photoList.load(gallery_id, current_page).then(function () {
    current_page++;
    console.log("Page Changed To : " + current_page);
    console.log("Gallery is  : " + gallery_id);
    loader.hide();
  }); 

};

HomePage.prototype.loadMorePhotos = function (args) {
  var timeout = setTimeout(getMorePhotos, 100);
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Comment: this must work , but problem for me is that loadMorePhotos is not in global context. it belongs to HomePage . however i set setTimeout(HomePage.loadMorePhotos, 100) . it doesn't works ..

Comment: Where did you put `setTimeout` ?

Comment: i've defined another functions within global context .  function loadMore(args){//set timeout here} . and this one is attached to loadmore attribute of list view

Comment: not working . just displays list view itself with first elements that are retrieved from view model . the height of list view even doesn't fit the page height and it seems that on load more never happens..